# What is the meaning of `copyOnWriteContext` in module `github.com/google/btree`?

Tags: b-tree

Recently, I read the source code of google/btree. But I'am conflused by the struct `copyOnWriteContext`. It is used in `node` function `mutableFor`, like following

```
func (n *node) mutableFor(cow *copyOnWriteContext) *node {
    if n.cow == cow {
        return n
    }
    fmt.Println("new node?")
    out := cow.newNode()
    if cap(out.items) >= len(n.items) {
        out.items = out.items[:len(n.items)]
    } else {
        out.items = make(items, len(n.items), cap(n.items))
    }
    copy(out.items, n.items)
    // Copy children
    if cap(out.children) >= len(n.children) {
        out.children = out.children[:len(n.children)]
    } else {
        out.children = make(children, len(n.children), cap(n.children))
    }
    copy(out.children, n.children)
    return out
}
```

I review all the code in this module, and found that there is only one place create the copyOnWriteContext's instance. It is when the tree is created.

```
func New(degree int) *BTree {
    return NewWithFreeList(degree, NewFreeList(DefaultFreeListSize))
}
```

So what is the meaning for `mutableFor`. Because there is only one `copyOnWriteContext` in the entire code. The `n.cow` always equals param `cow`.

Answer (score 0):

n.cow can be nil.

```golang
// freeNode frees a node within a given COW context, if it's owned by that
// context.  It returns what happened to the node (see freeType const
// documentation).
func (c *copyOnWriteContext) freeNode(n *node) freeType {
    if n.cow == c {
        // clear to allow GC
        n.items.truncate(0)
        n.children.truncate(0)
        n.cow = nil
        if c.freelist.freeNode(n) {
            return ftStored
        } else {
            return ftFreelistFull
        }
    } else {
        return ftNotOwned
    }
}
```